# What are the tax implications of exchanging one fund for another in a tax-sheltered account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, mutual-funds, roth-ira, vanguard

What are the tax implications (if any) for exchanging one fund for another in a tax sheltered account (Roth IRA)? e.g. Changing from, say, a Life Strategy Fund to a Target Retirement fund.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no tax consequences when you exchange funds in a tax-deferred account.

Comment: If you sold that same fund for a loss 30 days before or after the IRA purchase in an external account for a loss, the IRA purchase creates a wash sale. Really

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I guess I forgot that part. It really is a weird rule.....